# Pine script - Trying to add stop loss with value based on calculation

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to add a stop loss to a calculated value. The value for the stop loss is supposed to be the "up" calculation value. If I use the code below, my stop loss is above my long entry and I am not sure if it is the correct value either.

```
Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)

src = input(hl2, title="Source")

Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)

changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

//////

atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)

atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2

up=src-(Multiplier*atr)

up1 = nz(up[1],up)

up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up

trend = 1

trend := nz(trend[1], trend)

trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend

upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)

buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1

//// Stop loss calculation

Stoplosspercent = if buySignal
    (strategy.position_avg_price - up)/strategy.position_avg_price

/// Exit long

strategy.exit("long exit", "long", profit = strategy.position_avg_price*5/100/syminfo.mintick, loss = strategy.position_avg_price*Stoplosspercent/100/syminfo.mintick)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too bad that many users doesn't read [the official pine reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit):

- loss (series int/float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (**specified in ticks**).
- stop (series int/float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a **specific price**).
- profit (series int/float) An optional parameter. Profit target (**specified in ticks**).
- limit (series int/float) An optional parameter. Profit target (requires a **specific price**).

In your case you need to set up `limit` & `stop` parameters instead of `profit` & `loss` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for you help, I appreciate. Please bear with me as I only started coding yesterday. I have made the changes you recomended and it fixes half the problems. Thank you.

Comment: The remaining problem is, because there is a constant calculation with every bar, if I change exit to stop = up, then the stop moves up with every candle, where it should remain constant. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add your last actual script source and format it as `code` (tabs will not been "eated"). In short: you need make `var float Stoplosspercent` and modify it under some condition you needs: `if positionOpenedOrSomethingElse \n\tStoplosspercent :- ... `

Comment: Thanks, I managed to nail it with:value = close

if buySignal and close > ema2
    value := up
else
    if sellSignal and close < ema2
        value:= dn
    else
        value:= nz(value[1])
        
profitbuy = close

if buySignal and close > ema2
    profitbuy := ((close - value) * 2) + close
else
    profitbuy := nz(profitbuy[1])
    
profitsell = close

if sellSignal and close < ema2
    profitsell := close - ((value -close) * 2) 
else
    profitsell := nz(profitsell[1])